# decodeURIComponent in form querystring

Tags: javascript, jquery, decodeuricomponent

When i submit my form it will add `hidden` input as query string in browser url.

```js
$('form').on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // what i tried
    
    console.log($(this).attr('action'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="d" value="2,1">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

The result for this example is:

```
/box?d=2%2C1
```

But i don't want to see `%2C` (it's comma), i know about `decodeURIComponent` but i have know idea how to grab this form action and use this component on it, i tried this:

```
decodeURIComponent($(this).attr('action'));
```

But it return undefined.

**Goal:**

1. get form action + query string and use `decodeURIComponent` on it to remove `%2C`
   **OR**
2. remove `%2C` in query string in url with comma directly.

I want this result:

```
/box?d=2,1
```

Comment: you cant have commas in query strings, it has to be sent encoded

Comment: But there is no solution?  @mast3rd3mon

Comment: yes, decode it on the server

Comment: @NullDev i mean, get this `/box?d=2,1` before send to browser url , this is an action, isn't it?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I have no idea.. but how?

Comment: you would have to read it in the server code and decode it

Comment: what happens when you click the button, read the hidden value, encodeURIComponent it and finally when you read, decode it ! have you tried that?

Comment: Also if what the URL looks like bothers you, don't use GET, use POST.

Comment: @Kaddath no, i'm not worry about server side, i know about php decode urI. just worry about this annoying shape of `%2C`.

Comment: how is it annoying? its what it should be

Comment: @charlietfl that would still have to be encoded

Comment: @kandroid i can't `encodeURIComponent` because it goes to url automatically. when i click the button, it automatically append query strings to my url. this is what i asked, that how can i get this magic `action url` before it goes on browser url.

Comment: @mast3rd3mon just think it's bad to see `%2C` in url. i know it's naturally, but what you think about this? = >  `/box?d=2,1,3` or `/box?d=2%2C1%2C3` which one is readable and pretty?

Comment: but which of those actually works? think about usability, plus why does it matter how pretty it is?

Comment: `var result = "/box?d=" + $("input[name='d']").value()`

Comment: `/box?d=2:1:3` wouldn't look too bad..  or `/box?d=2.1.3`, just not comma, that's how browsers work.

Comment: @mast3rd3mon you absolutely right, but I am a bit obsessive.. this is no matter at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should only decode URIs server-side or if you receive this request in your client somehow, never on submit. URIs are encoded for safe "transport" (sometimes must be explicitly encoded). Code behavior is as expected or I fail to see your point.

Comment: Yea, @mast3rd3mon mentioned in comments. but i still thinking how can i do this in this case, This form all happened in client side, not server. how can i handle this form and action on server side? any example? guide or etc

Comment: First I would use POST method in conjunction with a form submit. Second, what's on your server?

Comment: using `php` on server

Comment: create a file with this, is basic behavior: <html>
 <form method="POST">
 <input type="hidden" name="d" value="2,1">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
 </form>
 <?php
 print_r($_POST);
 ?>
 </html>